# Squid as transparent proxy to tunnel all connections under Windows

Tags: active-directory, proxy, http, squid, ntlm

There's this app [Joplin](https://joplin.cozic.net/) that can't connect to the internet on a corporate machine which lives on Active Directory and connects to the internet through HTTP and a NTLM proxy.

The problem is that you can't configure Joplin to go through a proxy;there's no settings about it!So I was searching for a solution and if I understood correctly you can use Squid to enable all not proxy enabled apps to connect to Squid on the local machine and then Squid to forward the request to the NTLM proxy in order to access the internet.

First of all, is this assumption correct and then, how do I go about it? Any good references?

Comment: Did you find any information about the topic? I'm also looking for an NTLM proxy that is "smart" and intercepts all outgoing connections, so I do not have to configure each tool. Any help appreciated!